# C# - Possible of getting MDI parent through Application?

Tags: c#

This is my MDI Parent.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
        {
            public Options options {get; set;}
            public Project project {get; set;}


            public frmMain()
            {
                InitializeComponent();


            }
        }
```

My MDI child below need to access the project and option.

```
 public partial class frmInput : form
    {

        public frmInput(frmMain parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MdiParent = parent;

            //Of course I can do this
            Options options = ((frmMain) this.MdiParent).options;

           //But if I can have something as following, I can have 
           //a static method to access options in the frmMain anywhere.
           frmMain mainform = Application.MainForm;
           Options options = mainform.options;

        }
    }
```

If Application doesn't provide the access to the MdiParent, any other means that we can access it through static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you manually create a static field to do so? Something like:

```
public class frmMain {
    public static frmMain ApplicationMainWindow {get; private set;}
    public frmMain() {
        ApplicationMainWindow = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Other than that `Application.OpenForms` returns all open forms for the application and you can look it up to find the `frmMain` instance. It's a less than ideal solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This would work fine:

```
public partial class frmInput : form
    {
        private frmMain mainFrame;
        public frmInput(frmMain parent)
        {
            mainFrame = parent;
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MdiParent = parent;

            //Of course I can do this
            Options options = mainFrame.options;

        }
       private void Something() {
          Options o = mainFrame.options; //can access options now.
       }
    }
```

There's maybe more OO approaches that could be applied to decomple these classes though.